# Gaussian path integral in QFT in curved spacetime

Tags: metric-tensor, conventions, path-integral, covariance, qft-in-curved-spacetime

We have the expression for a Gaussian integral
$$I(A,b)=\int d^nx~ \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n,m}x_n A_{nm}x_m+\sum_{n}x_n b_n\right]=I(A,0)\exp\left[\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n,m}b_n\left(A^{-1}\right)_{nm}b_m\right],$$
which is always used in path integrals.

In QFT in curved spacetime, we have
$$\mathcal{Z}[J]=\int\mathcal{D}\phi \exp\left[-\frac{i}{2}\int dv_x\int dv_y~\phi(x)K(x,y)\phi(y)+i\int dv_x~J(x)\phi(x)\right],$$
where $dv_x=d^nx\sqrt{|\det g_{\mu\nu}(x)|}\equiv d^nx\sqrt{g(x)}$, and for a massive scalar field
$$K(x,y)=\left(\square_x+m^2\right)\delta(x,y),~~~~\square_x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g(x)}}\partial_\mu\left(\sqrt{g(x)}\partial^\mu\right),$$
where $\delta(x,y)$ is such that $f(x)=\int dv_y~ \delta(x,y)f(y)$.

My question is if

### Option 1

We have to consider $\sqrt{g}$ as part of the sumation, so $A_{nm}\to iK(x,y)$ and $b_n\to iJ(x)$; then
$$\mathcal{Z}[J]=\exp\left[\frac{i}{2}\int dv_x\int dv_y~J(x)K^{-1}(x,y)J(y)\right],$$
and
$$\int dv_y~ K(x,y)K^{-1}(y,z)=\delta(x,z)$$

### Option 2

We have to consider $\sqrt{g}$ as part of "$A$" and "$b$", so $A_{nm}\to i\sqrt{g(x)g(y)}K(x,y)\equiv i A(x,y)$ and $b_n\to i\sqrt{g(x)}J(x)$; then

$$\mathcal{Z}[J]=\exp\left[\frac{i}{2}\int dv_x\int dv_y~J(x)A^{-1}(x,y)J(y)\right]$$
and
$$\int d^ny~ A(x,y)A^{-1}(y,z)=\int dv_y~\sqrt{g(x)}K(x,y)A^{-1}(y,z)=\delta(x,z)$$

Comment: If you only want the $J$-dependence, it has little to do with your confusion. Simply follow the derivation of the finite-dimensional case: complete the square in the action and then shift $\phi$.

Comment: Well, this basically boils down to conventions and definitions.